# Hosted service in ASP.NET Core vs Worker Service

Tags: asp.net-core, architecture, asp.net-core-webapi, worker-service

For background process listening to a service bus topic, what would be the considerations for choosing between running a hosted service in ASP.NET core VS creating a worker service?

I'm seeing several options from the internet and I'm wondering which scenarios would make one go for each of these options:

1. Running API & Worker service separately
2. Running API with hosted service
3. Running worker service with API inside (not for us)

Our system will have an ASP.NET Core API as well, so I'm wondering whether to add a hosted service to this API or to separate the application as a worker service.

We also want to run this in container and deploy it in Azure container app (if that makes a difference to the considerations)

I saw someone mentioned if health check is needed for the background process then it's better to go with ASP.NET with hosted service implementation. But then I found this lib https://github.com/bruceharrison1984/TinyHealthCheck which seems to add health check functionality to worker service

Comment: i need to make the same decision. have you made up your mind? what did you use in the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API and the worker should be separated. You can then scale the two separately. Especially if you plan to deploy the worker on Azure Container App, you can scale automatically the worker depending on the message number on the bus [using KEDA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/scale-app#event-driven). When no message is in the queue it will automatically scale down to 0 !

Your API in the other hand should be always up.

To create a worker you should consider using the [generic host of .Net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is related with the relationship with the web api and the worker service.

If this worker service is just used for this asp.net core web api, I suggest you could choose 2 or 3.

If this work service is also used for other web api or else, I suggest you should run API & Worker service separately.

Comment: It's not used by the API. the worker service is listening to events (via service bus) and calling other APIs/ storing data in the database

Answer (score 0):

From the comments you have added I can see that the API and the worker service are separate and that you are deploying using docker. For those reasons I would suggest that you deploy these two things separately in their own containers. I would choose this because it makes each application simpler and easier to maintain.  A good place to start is here [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio). There is a simple dotnet cli template to create the project

```
dotnet new worker -o [your project name]
```